# Flutter TabBar indicatorPadding for all tabs

Tags: flutter

I want to use TabBar indicatorPadding for making the indicator little bit, that's why I added the following code:

```
indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 100.0)
```

but with the above code, the only first tab is showing perfectly and rest not. Please see the images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How to set all tabs indicatorPadding to same?

below is my code for TabBar:

```
TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      labelColor: Colors.white,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Minion Pro Regular',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 15.0),
      indicatorWeight: 2.0,
      indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,      
      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 100.0),
      isScrollable: true,
      tabs: <Widget>[
        Tab(
          text: 'Compare transport',
        ),
        Tab(
          text: 'Best price',
        ),
        Tab(
          text: 'Fastest way',
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "making the indicator little bit" do you want to make the tab indicator small in size?

Comment: I want all indicator size like the first one, that is the Compare transport tab.

Comment: My requirement is to set tab indicator of all tabs small size and start from starting of the label. Like the first image.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this behavior is due to the huge right padding set: `EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 100.0)`.

What you can do here is reduce the padding to 32.0 on both sides. The tab indicator fetches its width from `TabBarIndicatorSize.tab`.

```dart
indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0)
```

Doing so will result to this.

[image: Demo]

However, if you'd like to set a fixed tab indicator size, you'll need to create a custom TabBar. Currently you can only set the indicatorSize to either `TabBarIndicatorSize.tab` or `TabBarIndicatorSize.label`